# Is a set defined using a polynomial identity an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multivariate-polynomial

We consider a polynomial $F \in \mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots , X_n, Y_1, \ldots , Y_m]$ in $n+m$ variables. Define the set $A_F = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid F(x_1, \ldots , x_n, Y_1, \ldots , Y_m) = 0\}$ where equality is meant to be understood in the polynomial ring$\mathbb{C}[ Y_1, \ldots , Y_m]$. My question: Is $A_F$ an algebraic variety?

I would need to find a finite number of polynomials whose common roots are exactly $A_F$. It is easy to find a set of defing polynomials for $A_F$, namely $\{ F(X_1, \ldots , X_n, y_1, \ldots , y_m) \mid y \in \mathbb{C}^n \}$. This is true because for any $f \in \mathbb{C}[ Y_1, \ldots , Y_m]$ we have $f=0 \iff \forall y \in \mathbb{C}^n ~ f(y) = 0$. However these are infinitely many polynomials. Intuitively I should be able to pick a finite number of those, but I don't see a convincing argument why this suffices.

And assuming that you *can* pick out finitely many of these polynomials, how many (if chosen randomly) would suffice to describe $A_F$ almost surely?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You're kind of barking up the wrong tree here. Hint: write $F$ as a polynomial in the $Y_i$ with coefficients in the $X_i$.

Comment: @KReiser That is how I think of $F$. As an element of $\mathbb{C}[X_1, \ldots , X_n] [Y_1, \ldots , Y_m]$. But why the set of coefficients $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ that make $F$ vanish as a polynomial is a variety is precisely my question, so I see no information in that hint.

Comment: Exanding the hint by KReiser: write $F = \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_m} c_{i_1,\dots,i_m}(X_1,\dots,X_n) Y_1^{i_1} \cdots Y_m^{i_m}$. Then  $A_F = V(\{c_{i_1,\dots,i_m}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \mid i_1,\dots,i_m\})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my hint in to an answer: Write $F=\sum_\alpha p_\alpha(X_1,\cdots,X_n)Y^\alpha$ as a polynomial in the $Y_i$ with coefficients in the $X_j$ where $\alpha$ is a multi-index to save us some notation. Then the set you describe is exactly the zero locus of all of the $p_\alpha$, of which there are finitely many because a polynomial has only finitely many nonzero coefficients.